# DlalogAlert wont show

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am a novice in xamarin,

I am trying to display a dialog Alert when I select an item in my listview but it is not working

here my xaml code:

```
   <!-- Overlay WordList  -->
                        <ContentView  x:Name="WordListView" >
                            <StackLayout  Padding="0,10,0,0">
                                    <ListView x:Name="WordSList"
                                                ItemSelected="OnSelectedTestHelp"
                                                HasUnevenRows="True"
                                                IsPullToRefreshEnabled="true"
                                                Refreshing="OnRefresh" >
                                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                <ViewCell >
                                                    <ViewCell.ContextActions>
                                                        <MenuItem Clicked="OnUpdate" Text="Update"   CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                                                        <MenuItem Clicked="OnComplete" Text="Delete"   CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                                                    </ViewCell.ContextActions>
                                                    <StackLayout Padding="10,5,5,5" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" Orientation="Vertical">
                                                        <Label TextColor="Black" Text="{Binding Vocabulary}"  FontSize="15" />
                                                        <Label TextColor="Black" Text="{Binding Reminder}"  FontSize="12" />
                                                    </StackLayout>
                                                </ViewCell>
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                    </ListView>
                                </StackLayout>

                        </ContentView>
                        <!-- END Overlay WordList  -->
```

Here is my code with the function "OnSelectedTestHelp" :

```
 public   void OnSelectedTestHelp(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
        {

           DisplayAlert("Help ! ", "Reminder :", "✔");
           Console.WriteLine("####");// I can see this out put
        }
```

sorry for my novice question

Comment: have you tried it with plaintext instead of the checkmark?

Comment: Yes it is still  not working

Comment: is this class inheriting from a Page type?

Comment: yes : public partial class TestWordsPage : ContentPage

Comment: @kikis I can't see where do you use your func `OnSelectedTestHelp` in your xaml. `ItemSelected="OnSelectedWordDescript"` - you have another event on list item clicked?

Comment: it is a bad copy paste, sorry

Answer (score 1):

Code with the function "OnSelectedTestHelp" ,there's a problem there:

```
 public void OnSelectedTestHelp(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
       DisplayAlert("Help ! ", "Reminder :", "✔");
       Console.WriteLine("####");// I can see this out put
    }
```

Since the property you added in xaml is `ItemSelected="OnSelectedTestHelp"` , you should use `SelectedItemChangedEventArgs` in function.

### More info:

If you use `ItemTapped="xxx"` in xaml , there will use `ItemTappedEventArgs` in function.

```
public event EventHandler<Xamarin.Forms.SelectedItemChangedEventArgs> ItemSelected;
public event EventHandler<Xamarin.Forms.ItemTappedEventArgs> ItemTapped;
```

You can refer to [this demo](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/UserInterface/ListView/interactivity/)